# Psionics in XCOM (ipad version)

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I am quite far in this game have plasma weapons full satellite coverage.
I have not yet found a sectoid commander and don't have Psionics researched.
Have I progressed incorrectly. I played on the PC and seem to remember encountering sectoid commanders fairly early.

Is there a glitch?

Comment: as i remember, sectoid commanders only appear after you have captured a outsider shard and researched its key to the `mothership`. sound familiar to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer with spoilers:

The first Sectoid Commanders you will meet will be

> In charge of the alien base.

As Ken said in his comment, you should not expect to meet them before capturing an Outsider and doing the research and mission that follows.

Comment: I didn't do the mission in the spoiler, I deliberately left it out because I wanted to progress slowly. I didn't realize it was so important. Good reason to start again.

Comment: @Jim hmmm. as i remember there's no way you can't do that mission. same as mine, i left about 3 three months and when im ready to commit i just played it.